# asyncio run or run_until_complete

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am using `asyncio` for an application in a very basic way. Checking most tutorials around the internet (and even the official docs), I see that they use the `get_event_loop()` and `loop.run_until_complete()`:

```py
import asyncio

async def say(what, when):
    await asyncio.sleep(when)
    print(what)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(say('hello world', 1))
loop.close()
```

But in the [Python 3.7 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html), we can read:

> Application developers should typically use the high-level asyncio functions, such as [asyncio.run()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run), and should rarely need to reference the loop object or call its methods. This section is intended mostly for authors of lower-level code, libraries, and frameworks, who need finer control over the event loop behavior.

I found it much cleaner and easier to use, but it only works for Python 3.7+. So here I would have to make a choice, whether to use Python 3.7+ and `run()` or make it compatible with Python 3.6 and use the event loop. How would you manage this? Is there a simple way to make it backwards compatible with Python 3.6? Should I check Python version first and use either one way or another based on that, until Python 3.7 becomes a common version?

Comment: If you're going to write *more complicated code* that works on both versions, *and* simpler code for newer versions, and you'll switch dynamically between them… isn't it easier to simply stick with the more complicated one that works on both?

Comment: @deceze yes, maybe that's the best option, I wanted to have an opinion on that and in the case of making it compatible, to know which is the best way to do so

Comment: @deceze Emulating `asyncio.run` on older Python versions is not hard, and you get the advantage that you test your code under the conditions set up by `asyncio.run`, i.e. on a freshly created event loop.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to make [code making use of `asyncio.run`] backwards compatible with Python 3.6?

You can implement a simple substitute for `asyncio.run` and call it on older Python versions:

```
import asyncio, sys, types

def run(coro):
    if sys.version_info >= (3, 7):
        return asyncio.run(coro)

    # Emulate asyncio.run() on older versions

    # asyncio.run() requires a coroutine, so require it here as well
    if not isinstance(coro, types.CoroutineType):
        raise TypeError("run() requires a coroutine object")

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    try:
        return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
    finally:
        loop.close()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(None)
```

The advantage of this approach over just using `loop.run_until_complete()` is that you're executing your code under the semantics close to those of the new `asyncio.run`, even on older Python versions. (For example, you will always run on a freshly created event loop.) Dropping support for pre-3.7 Python will be as easy as removing the `run` shim and calling `asyncio.run` directly.

Comment: Nice! This looks great! I will try this :) Thanks!

Comment: just a minor thing on your code, the condition should be `sys.version_info >= (3, 7)`. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Suspect the order of the 2 lines in the `finally` block should not be the opposite of that in the Python standard library (the other answer on this question)

Comment: @LouisMaddox I don't think it matters, but if in doubt, feel free to reverse the order

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to replicate `asyncio.run` by copying the code from the asyncio.runners.py. The one below is [from Python 3.8](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/asyncio/runners.py).

```
from asyncio import coroutines, events, tasks


def run(main, *, debug=False):
    """Execute the coroutine and return the result.

    This function runs the passed coroutine, taking care of
    managing the asyncio event loop and finalizing asynchronous
    generators.

    This function cannot be called when another asyncio event loop is
    running in the same thread.

    If debug is True, the event loop will be run in debug mode.

    This function always creates a new event loop and closes it at the end.
    It should be used as a main entry point for asyncio programs, and should
    ideally only be called once.

    Example:

        async def main():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            print('hello')

        asyncio.run(main())
    """
    if events._get_running_loop() is not None:
        raise RuntimeError(
            "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop")

    if not coroutines.iscoroutine(main):
        raise ValueError("a coroutine was expected, got {!r}".format(main))

    loop = events.new_event_loop()
    try:
        events.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.set_debug(debug)
        return loop.run_until_complete(main)
    finally:
        try:
            _cancel_all_tasks(loop)
            loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
        finally:
            events.set_event_loop(None)
            loop.close()


def _cancel_all_tasks(loop):
    to_cancel = tasks.all_tasks(loop)
    if not to_cancel:
        return

    for task in to_cancel:
        task.cancel()

    loop.run_until_complete(
        tasks.gather(*to_cancel, loop=loop, return_exceptions=True))

    for task in to_cancel:
        if task.cancelled():
            continue
        if task.exception() is not None:
            loop.call_exception_handler({
                'message': 'unhandled exception during asyncio.run() shutdown',
                'exception': task.exception(),
                'task': task,
            })
```

Comment: In [version 3.9](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/asyncio/runners.py) they added `loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_default_executor())` after the `shutdown_asyncgens` (otherwise identical), and no change in 3.10